# Find the number of Primes less than $2^{2^{100}}$

Tags: number-theory

The number of primes less than $2^{2^{100}}$ is $(a)101$   $(b)100$ $(c) 2^{100}$ $(c)2^{101}$.

How can I solve this ? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you got the question correct?

Comment: yes.... This question was given in Visva-Bharati University Admission test for M.Sc. -2016 .But I can't understand how to solve it...!!

Comment: To get a good approximation of $\pi(2^{2^{100}})$, you should use the li-function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), the prime numbers are asymptotically distributed according to
$$
\pi(n) \approx \frac n{\ln n}\ ,
$$ 
where $\pi(n)$ is the number of primes less than or equal to $n$. This shows that for $n=2^{2^{100}}$ we'd have 
$$
\pi(n) \approx \frac {2^{2^{100}}}{\ln 2^{2^{100}}}=\frac {2^{2^{100}}}{2^{100}\ln 2} \approx 2^{(2^{100}-99)}
$$ 
which is nowhere near any values you proposed.

This is why I asked if you got the question correct or not.

Comment: hmm...I think u r right ...the University made a misstake..@ BibbearZzz

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{x}{ln(x)}$=number of primes until x (for large enough x, the error becomes almost nill)

i think the rest is easy, btw search prime number theorem :)

Comment: I know this theorem ...But here $x$ is so large,...$x=2^{2^{100}}$....how can i find the value of $x/ln(x)$..?

Comment: The relative error becomes small, but the absolute error is still big. It would be interesting how accurate the number of primes below $2^{2^{100}}$ can be determined.